# php web page not loading

Tags: php, html, apache2

I am not an expert but I am no noob at PHP, yet for whatever reason I am stomped as to why my document will not load. Here is my code.

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Home</title>
</head>

<body>

<p>Hello everyone</p>

</body>

</html>
```

When I pull out the PHP portion the HTML loads fine. Here is the code in my header.php file.

```
<?php
<href="index.php">Home</a>
?>
```

I have tried this on two different hosts, both of which are hosting other PHP websites and still getting issues. I have also validated it with W3Schools and another online PHP validator. Both didn't find any errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `<href="index.php">Home</a>` is **not** valid HTML

Comment: And no valid PHP either ;)

Comment: Basic HTML and PHP 101, not done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable errors to see errors, this way:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

This code is a PHP error:

```
<?php
<href="index.php">Home</a>
?>
```

Try change to:

```
<?php
echo '<href="index.php">Home</a>';
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
<?php
<href="index.php">Home</a>
?>
```

Is no valid PHP. This would, however work:

```
<a href="index.php">Home</a>
```

Inside of the PHP-tags you can only use PHP - no HTML. Also, `<href>` is no HTML tag.

Look at this question [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php) to find out, how to enable error messages in PHP.